# Slowly Changing Dimension Type 1 - access

Tags: sql, ms-access, scd

Say I have a product table which contains a descriptions mistake. The unit of measurement was misspelled as “garms” instead of “grams”. How would this be implemented with a query statement to represent type 1 - SCD technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get an answer for this question. I was looking for something like this:

```
Begin

SELECT all from Product Table
UPDATE Product Table
   SET [Product Unit of Measure] = “grams”
   WHERE [Product Unit of Measure] = “garms”

End
```